# How does operator overloading work inconjuction to function overloading

Tags: operator-overloading

How does operator overloading work inconjuction to function overloading. I mean I don't quite understand how to overload an operator using a function that has been overloaded itslef.

Comment: In what programming language? Can you provide example of what you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Operator` is just a funky name given to infix functions (the ones written between their arguments). So, `1 + 2` is just a `+(1, 2)`. `Overloading` means that you define several functions (or operators, which are the same thing) like this:

```
int square(int x);
double square(double x);

int operator + (int x, int y);
double operator + (double x, double y); // *
```

When these get called somewhere else, C++ determines which one to call not only by name, but also by the types of the actual arguments. So when you write `square(5)` the first one gets called and when you write `square(5.0)` the second one does. Beware that in more complex cases overload resolution (determining which function to call) is [much more tricky](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c++%20overloading).

Possibly you mean the situation, when your operator is overloaded not as a function, but as a method (i.e. it's first argument is passed using [`thiscall`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ek8tkfbw.aspx)), and you'd like to overload a binary operator on it's second argument. [Here's how it's done.](http://ideone.com/o9MJUE)

(*) Actually, you cannot declare `operator +` for `int` and `double`, because these are built in into a compiler.

Comment: Ohhhh. Ook I get it I was just confused on what overloading meant and how the function that uses it would look like.